What is the relationship between the terms "association", "aggregation", and "composition"?
I try to brush up on my technical interview skills as I plan to seek a better offer
I don't recall being ever asked that really, but I still want to clear up any confusion. What is association, aggregation, and composition? As I understand

Composition is a type of aggregation, aggregation is a type of composition
With aggregation, the contained object may outlive the containing one; with composition, the lifecycles of the container and the contained object match (once the container dies, the contained object dies too)

What I don't understand

Does association itself imply a has-a relationship?
Are there other types of association besides aggregation?
Are there other types aggregation besides composition? E.g. is there a word for that "looser" aggregation that is not composition?

This question is similar, but it doesn't really answer my questions

top google result : https://www.infoworld.com/article/2243500/exploring-association-aggregation-and-composition-in-oop.html#:~:text=Aggregation%20in%20object%20oriented%20programming,may%20not%20denote%20physical%20containment.

@Ewan "top google result" that is a strong hint I may have already seen it

yeah i guess im wondering what exactly you are asking, the defintions seem pretty clear?

This question is similar to: What is the use of Association, Aggregation and Composition?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See also: C++ : Association, Aggregation and Composition

Or Is composition and aggregation really a type of association relationship?

Or Differences between Direct, Composition, Aggregation, and Temporary Association

This question is definitely not opinion based, since it is about standardized terms. One could claim it is a duplicate, but this questions seems to add on them, I think.

@Ewan the article still refers to aggregation while UML no longer defines semantics for it. So it is obsolete or uses a non-standard interpretation of what it could be (or what it initially used to mean, whereas nobody ever managed to define a clear objective criteria to single it out)

I guess its late now, but you could have specified a UML answer

The question itself doesn't specify if it is referring to UML or not (needs focus), if the question is referring to UML then the question is a dup, if it is not referencing UML then it is option based.

These terms are standardised by the UML Specifications:

Association means there is a semantic relationship between instances of two classes.
Aggregation, the short name of "shared aggregation" has no longer any specific semantic defined in the UML standard since its version 2, more almost 20 years ago. The only guarantee it gives is that there can be no cycle when several classes are aggregated between them.  Yet people continue to use this "modelling placebo" (the term is from J.Rumbaugh, one of the convenor of UML).  People us it to express a "has a" relationship, but in reality, in absence of specific semantics,  it's the same than a simple association (UML 2 has introduced the dot notation to better express a "has a" relationship", unfortunately even today not many tools support it).
Composition, the short name of "composite aggregation" (and not to be confused with "object composition" which is a general OOP term) is meant to express a part/whole relationship with exclusive ownership of some instances of one class (the part) by an instance of the other class (the whole), in particular that the composed parts are destroyed when the composite whole is destroyed.

Beside this, there are:

dependency: the loosest form of relationship, where one class needs to know about another class, for example because it uses it in some of its operations (but not necessarily).
generalization:  this is inheritance
realization:  this means that one class implements an interface

Note: UML was defined in the 90's where multiple object oriented modelling techniques existed, and one company managed to hire the 3 leading modelling techniques to make a single "unified" one, and clarifying the terms to avoid ambiguity. Later this standard was given to the OMG, a standard making body.

In the strict context of UML class diagrams there are 3 broads sets of arrows that can be used to connect classes/interfaces:

Realization and Generalization/Inheritance - Implementing interfaces and Inheritance.
Dependencies - where a class is used (for example inside a method), but not stored as a member variable.
Association, Aggregation and Composition - Where a class has a member variable that references another class.

The full definitions of these terms (in the context of UML class diagrams) are well documented in many blogs, books etc - I will save the reader time and not repeat them.

However in common parlance:
Association - Is not well defined, most likely it refers to a reference or a pointer, however it could also be used "sloppily" to just mean there is some connection to another class (any of the UML types). For that reason, I would tend not to use it, except when talking about UML diagrams.
Outside of UML diagrams Aggregation and Composition are typically used somewhat interchangeably.

In object-oriented design these terms usually describe relationships between classes. They define how objects of one class relate to objects of another.
1. Association

Definition: Association is a general relationship between two classes where objects of one class interact with objects of another. It is a weak, semantic relationship without strong ownership. Each object has its own lifecycle.
Nature: Objects exist independently of each other. For example, a Teacher interacts with multiple Students, but neither class owns the other. Each can be created or destroyed independently. The association simply provides a communication path between objects.
Multiplicity: Associations often involve multiplicity, such as one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many relationships.
Representation in UML: An association is represented by a simple line between two classes.

Example:
class Teacher {};
class Student {
    Teacher *myTeacher;  // Association: Student interacts with a Teacher
};

2. Aggregation

Definition: Aggregation is a specialised form of association representing a whole-part relationship, where the parts (children) can exist independently of the whole (parent).
Nature: Aggregation implies loose coupling. The part (e.g., Player) has an independent lifecycle from the whole (e.g., Team). If a Team is destroyed, the Player objects remain. The ownership is unidirectional, meaning the parent can "own" the part, but the part does not own the parent.
Representation in UML: Aggregation is shown by a line with an empty diamond at the parent class (the whole).
Multiplicity: Aggregation often involves one-to-many or many-to-many relationships.

Example:
class Player {};
class Team {
    std::vector<Player*> players;  // Aggregation: Team contains Players
};

3. Composition

Definition: Composition is a stronger form of aggregation where the whole (parent) owns the parts (children) and controls their lifecycle. If the parent object is destroyed, the child objects are also destroyed. Composition is often referred to as a "death relationship" because the destruction of the parent leads to the destruction of the children.
Nature: Composition implies strong coupling. The lifetime of the parts (eg., Room) is tied to the lifetime of the whole (eg., House). If the house is destroyed, so are the rooms. The parent directly controls the creation and destruction of the child objects, although this control can also be transitive, meaning the parent may delegate the responsibility of controlling the child’s lifecycle to another object.
Representation in UML: Composition is represented by a line with a filled diamond at the parent class (the whole).
Multiplicity: A whole can own multiple parts, but the parts cannot exist independently of the whole.

Example:
class Room {};
class House {
    std::vector<Room> rooms;  // Composition: House owns Rooms
    ~House() {
        // When a House is destroyed, the Rooms are also destroyed
        rooms.clear();
    }
};

In the above example, House directly owns its Room objects. When the House is destroyed, the rooms are also destroyed, reflecting their dependent lifecycle.
Relationship Between the Terms:

Association: A general relationship with no ownership, where objects can communicate but have independent lifecycles.
Aggregation: A whole-part relationship with loose coupling where parts can exist independently of the whole.
Composition: A whole-part relationship with strong coupling, where parts cannot exist independently of the whole and are destroyed when the whole is destroyed (a "death relationship").


In composition a part can perfectly exist without the whole,  if the multiplicity on the whole side is 0..1 .  Also,  the ownership of a part can perfectly be transferred to another whole, keeping the part alive longer than its original whole ;-)

Hi @Christophe, thanks for the comment, which is very interesting ! Maybe I need to refresh my understanding: I thought that composition implies a strong lifecycle dependency: parts cannot exist without the whole, and when the whole is destroyed, the parts are also destroyed. Isn't that why it sometimes called a "death relationship"? With a multiplicity of 0..1 on the whole, parts can temporarily exist without a parent and ownership can be transferred. But doesn't that flexibility align more closely with aggregation, where parts can exist independently and have loose coupling with the whole.

Yes, it is a strong relationship as you describe. However It may feel strange at first, but nothing in the standard requires the absence of link of the part to be temporary when it's 0..1. There are perfectly valid models where one object can be created as component of another, but the same kind of object could be created as standalone as well, wheteher it'll end up as component of stays independent. Aggregation has no longer a standardized semantics. But if it would, the key is that a part can be shared by several aggregates at the same time, whereas composition is an exclusive ownership.
